# σ-field expectation problem

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> Let $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ be two σ-fields and suppose $\mathcal G⊂\mathcal F$. Let $X$ be an $\mathcal F$-measurable random variable and $Y$ be a $\mathcal G$-measurable random variable. Assume that $E(X^2)<∞$ and $E(Y^2)<∞$. Show that $$E(X-E(X\mid\mathcal{G}))^2\leqslant E(X-Y)^2.$$

Thank you for helping.

Comment: This will depend on how you defined conditional expectation.

Comment: @Ian I do not understand what you mean by that.

Comment: @drhab For instance you can define conditional expectation of an $L^2$ variable $X$ with respect to $\mathcal{G}$ to be the $L^2$-projection of $X$ onto the $\mathcal{G}$-measurable functions (in which case you need to define the conditional expectation of a $L^1$ random variable as a limit, of course). In this case this result is automatic. Also when I said "this" I meant the proof, the result holds regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y$ and $\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]$ are both $\mathcal{G}$-measurable
so that: $$\mathbb{E}\left(XY\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[XY\mid\mathcal{G}\right]\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]Y\right)$$
and likewise: $$\mathbb{E}\left(X\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[X\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]\mid\mathcal{G}\right]\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]^{2}\right)$$

This tells us that: $$\mathbb{E}\left(X-\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]\right)\left(\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]-Y\right)=$$$$\mathbb{E}\left(X\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]\right)-\mathbb{E}\left(XY\right)-\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]^{2}\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]Y\right)=0$$

so that $$\mathbb{E}\left(X-Y\right)^{2}=\mathbb{E}\left(X-\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]-Y\right)^{2}=$$$$\mathbb{E}\left(X-\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]\right)^{2}+\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]-Y\right)^{2}\geq\mathbb{E}\left(X-\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid\mathcal{G}\right]\right)^{2}$$